# How to set trailing stop loss for backtesting on Google Bigquery if possible

Tags: google-bigquery, quantitative-finance, back-testing

so I am doing some backtesting for some trading strategies on the stock market on Google Bigquery and I would like to set a trailing stop loss of 1% away from the entered price. If the stock price went up by let's say 5%, the trailing stop loss will move up 5% as well. If the stock price went down, the trailing stop loss will not change. (https://www.investopedia.com/terms/t/trailingstop.asp)

I have this table which shows my signal to enter and the exit column will show a value of 1 if the price goes below the trailing stop loss price, which means the trade is exited.

This is the table I have so far:

```
date           price      entry_signal      
30/06/2018     95              0                
01/07/2018     100             1                
02/07/2018     103             0                
03/07/2018     105             0                
04/07/2018     104.50          0                
05/07/2018     101             0
```

I would like to have a column showing what is the trailing stop loss at every date. The trailing stop loss is first set as 99% of the price on 01/07/2018 when the enter_signal = 1, where trade is executed on this date.

When the price moves up by y%, the trailing stop loss will move up by y% as well. However if the price goes down, the trailing stop loss will not change from its last value.

When the price <= trailing stop loss, the trade is exited and there will be an exit_signal of 1...

I am currently stuck at not having the trailing stop loss to move down by y% if the price move down by y% as well....

Desired table outcome:

```
date           price      trailing stop loss      entry_signal      exit_signal
30/06/2018     95              NULL                     0                0
01/07/2018     100             99                       1                0
02/07/2018     103             101.97                   0                0
03/07/2018     105             103.95                   0                0
04/07/2018     104.50          103.95                   0                0
05/07/2018     101             103.95                   0                1
```

This was my original code:

```
SELECT 
date, price, entry_signal,
GREATEST(trailing_stop_loss, 0.99 * price) AS trailing_stop_loss
FROM (
SELECT
date, price, entry_signal,
LAST_VALUE(trailing_stop_loss IGNORE NULLS) OVER (ORDER BY DATE) AS trailing_stop_loss
FROM (
SELECT
 date, price, entry_signal,
IF(entry_signal * 0.99 * price > 0, 0.99 * price, NULL) AS trailing_stop_loss
FROM table
)
)
```

Table I have obtained:

```
date           price      trailing stop loss      entry_signal      
30/06/2018     95              NULL                     0                
01/07/2018     100             99                       1                
02/07/2018     103             101.97                   0                
03/07/2018     105             103.95                   0                
04/07/2018     104.50          103.455                  0                
05/07/2018     101             99.99                    0
```

Comment: "I am currently stuck at  ..." - can you show the query you stuck with?

Comment: Hi Mikail, thank you for offering to help again!

Comment: Hi @MikhailBerlyant I have added my code and the table I have obtained from the code. I cannot think of how to obtain the trailing_stop_loss in my desired table as you can see as compared to my code. The exit_signal can only be obtained if the trailing_stop_loss is done properly, exit_signal = 1 if price <= trailing_stop_loss

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> I am currently **stuck at** not having the trailing stop loss to move down by y% if the price move down by y% as well....

```
#standardSQL
WITH temp1 AS (
  SELECT day, price, entry_signal,
    UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', day)) day_as_days,
    COUNTIF(entry_signal = 1) OVER(ORDER BY UNIX_DATE(PARSE_DATE('%d/%m/%Y', day))) grp
  FROM `project.dataset.table`
), temp2 AS (
  SELECT day, price,
    0.99 * price AS trailing_stop_loss,
    IFNULL(price > LAG(price) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY day_as_days), TRUE) AS up,
    entry_signal, grp, day_as_days
  FROM temp1
)
SELECT day, price, trailing_stop_loss, entry_signal, 
  IF(price > trailing_stop_loss, 0, 1) AS exit_signal
FROM (
  SELECT day_as_days, day, price, entry_signal,
    IF(up, trailing_stop_loss, arr[OFFSET(0)]) trailing_stop_loss
  FROM (
    SELECT day_as_days, day, price, up, trailing_stop_loss, entry_signal,
      ARRAY_AGG(trailing_stop_loss) OVER(PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY IF(up, day_as_days, 0) DESC) arr
    FROM temp2
  )
)
-- ORDER BY day_as_days
```

with result

```
Row day         price   trailing_stop_loss  entry_signal    exit_signal  
1   30/06/2018  95.0    94.05               0               0    
2   01/07/2018  100.0   99.0                1               0    
3   02/07/2018  103.0   101.97              0               0    
4   03/07/2018  105.0   103.95              0               0    
5   04/07/2018  104.5   103.95              0               0    
6   05/07/2018  101.0   103.95              0               1
```

> Desired table outcome:  ...

As you can see, above query at least partially addresses your `stuck at` point - while I am not sure what the whole picture is and what else needs to be addressed - even if your overall problem is still not fully addressed  - i feel like your particular question is answered.

So, I hope above will unblock you and you can complete your challenge by yourself :o)

Btw, I used below dummy data (from your question)

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT '30/06/2018' day, 95 price, 0 entry_signal UNION ALL
  SELECT '01/07/2018', 100, 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT '02/07/2018', 103, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '03/07/2018', 105, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '04/07/2018', 104.50, 0 UNION ALL
  SELECT '05/07/2018', 101, 0 
)
```